# MS Graph API for OneDrive: increase expiration time for upload session

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I want to upload to OneDrive with Microsoft Graph API for OneDrive very large file. According to documentation [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/driveitem_createuploadsession) I must finish my upload process before expirationTime. Unfortunately in all my tests MS Graph API gives me only 15 minutes for finishing my upload. But in my case it's too little time range for upload. And as I see in documentation, there is no way to continue uploading after upload session expiration.

My question is: is there any workaround for this? What should I do if e.g. I need 2 hours for uploading a file with MS Graph API?

Comment: I don't believe so but, more importantly, 2hrs is an awfully long upload time. How large is the file and how slow is the connection?

Comment: E.g. I have a file 100+ Gib (image of virtual machine)

Comment: OneDrive has a maximum file size of 20 GB. You'll need to split that file and restitch them if/when you need to restore it.

Comment: Are you completing a single chunk in 15 minutes or is it taking more than 15 minutes for a single chunk? To my knowledge each successful chunk should trigger a reset of the timeout

Comment: @MarcLaFleur What about case when I can't finish an upload process of 20 Gib file in 15 min time range?

Comment: @Brad What do you mean under chunk? PUT request with bytes? If every successful PUT request resets a timeout, why this important detail isn't clarified in documentation? Why I am asking - it's very important for our case: we want to upload to OneDrive over MS Graph API large files (as Marc mentioned above - a lot of 20 Gib files). And according to current version of documentation, we cannot do it. 

P.S. If expiration date is updated with every successful PUT request, can you add a note about this to the documentation please?